# How to connect Nodemcu ESP-32s and GSM SIM800L

Tags: esp32, nodemcu, gsm

The code that I use:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(16, 17); 

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ"); //Signal quality test, value range is 0-31 , 31 is the best
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CCID"); //Read SIM information to confirm whether the SIM is plugged
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CREG?"); //Check whether it has registered in the network
  updateSerial();
}

void loop()
{
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

but if I run it, the GSM doesn't seem to respond or it show me different characters as its output "???".

Connection:

| SIM800L | Nodemcu ESP-32s |
| --- | --- |
| RX | GIOP17 |
| TX | GIOP16 |

[image]

[image]

the expected output:

[image]

the output I have:
[image]

Comment: how do you know that the GSM module is not responding? ... please edit your post with a description of what you expected to happen and what you observed

Comment: why don't you use hardware serial, instead of software serial?

Comment: The by default baud rate of sim800 is `115200` try using this baud rate if it works if it works then try changing the baudrate using AT command `AT+IPR=<baudrate>` and then use `AT&W` to store the baud rate